# How can I search for a word in a file which is preceded and followed by a space in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, search

I want to search a file line by line for a particular word but I want to make sure that this particular word is being preceded and followed by a space.

I know that I have to do this using regex. I've been reading [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) guide but it's confusing to me how to apply both lookahead and lookbehind in the same statement.

How can I do this?

```
counter = 0
out = open('out.txt', 'w')
with open(original_db, 'r') as db:
    for line in db:
        if re.search(word, line, re.IGNORECASE):
            counter += 1
            out.write(line)
print("Entries found for word: " + str(counter))
```

Comment: Why not `split` the line and check if the word is present in the resulting list?

Comment: can include the sample lines?

Comment: Please include more details, otherwise, it is not clear. Does it mean you also want to only match the "word"  if it is not at the start/end of the line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add *word boundary* anchors, `\b`, to your pattern:

```
if re.search('\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(word)), line, re.IGNORECASE):
```

These only match when a word character (a-z, 0-9 or `_` characters) is preceded or followed by another, non-word character. This is broader than whitespace; words preceded or followed by punctuation also work.

If you must only match words that are whitespace-separated, then don't use a regular expression; just split on whitespace:

```
if word in line.lower().split():
```

Comment: Too fast for me as usual, nice answer :)

Comment: `if re.search('\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(word)), line, re.IGNORECASE):` returned zero results but the splitter worked fine. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Hopefully you filled the variable 'word' with your word?

Comment: @Aventinus without seeing a sample word that's hard to debug. Glad splitting works.